# Why is the following code not adding a role to the user?

Tags: discord, discord.js

In the following code, i am trying to add a role to a user whenever a user reacts the "A" emoji to a specific message. However, when I react to the message, I only see the console log `Role Added1`, meaning the thread is stuck in the line trying assigning roles to the user. What have I done wrong in the following code causing the error?

```js
bot.on("raw", event => {
    const eventName = event.t;

    if(eventName == "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){

        var roles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("roles.json"));
        var info = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("info.json"))

        if(event.d.message_id == info["Class Message"]){//class selection
            switch(event.d.emoji.name){
                case "":
                    console.log("Role Added1");
                    event.d.member.roles.add(bot.guilds.cache.get("721695624613068830")
                    .roles.cache.get(roles["myrole"]));
                    console.log("Role Added2");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not receiving a `GuildMember` class instance from the `raw` event. It's a simple json object, it has nothing to do with discordjs. Here is something working:

```js
bot.on("raw", async event => {
    const eventName = event.t;

    if(eventName == "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){

        var roles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("roles.json"));
        var info = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("info.json"))

        if(event.d.message_id == info["Class Message"]){//class selection
            switch(event.d.emoji.name){
                case "":
                    console.log("Role Added1");
                    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("721695624613068830");
                    const memberID = event.d.user_id;
                    const member = await guild.members.fetch(memberID);
                    member.roles.add(roles["myrole"]);
                    console.log("Role Added2");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use the following to make your event function synchronous:

```js
bot.on("raw", event => {
    const eventName = event.t;

    if(eventName == "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){

        var roles = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("roles.json"));
        var info = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("info.json"))

        if(event.d.message_id == info["Class Message"]){//class selection
            switch(event.d.emoji.name){
                case "":
                    console.log("Role Added1");
                    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("721695624613068830");
                    const memberID = event.d.user_id;
                    guild.members.fetch(memberID).then((member) => {
                            member.roles.add(roles["myrole"]);
                            console.log("Role Added2");
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why does the event need to be async?

Comment: because I used "await guild.members.fetch". The `await` keyword can only be used in asynchronous functions.

Comment: but if the function is not async, you do not need the await keyword to make the fetch function blocking

Comment: Yes you'll need it. Fetching the user takes time and returns a promise, so you need it to be resolved. I will update my answer with another solution to show you.

Comment: thanks, for the help, I am just applying my knowledge of other languages into js xD